# ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused - MQTT.connect()

Tags: python, mqtt

I would like some ideas please to catch the error below.
I know what caused the error - I stopped the mosquitto service.
This is a test case because in the real world the broker is on another machine (controlled by HomeAssistant)

In the case of an overall restart / power failure etc there is no guarantee what order devices restart in.
I would like this slave to quietly retry until everything is OK.
I was hoping it could be controlled in the on_connect callback but it never gets that far
it is crashing on the 'G_mqtt_client.connect' call

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Code/watering_ctrl_1v00.py", line 382, in <module>
    mqtt_initialisation()
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Code/watering_ctrl_1v00.py", line 202, in mqtt_initialisation
    G_mqtt_client.connect(params.G_broker_url, params.G_broker_port)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 914, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1044, in reconnect
    sock = self._create_socket_connection()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3685, in _create_socket_connection
    return socket.create_connection(addr, timeout=self._connect_timeout, source_address=source)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 843, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 831, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

relevant part of my code

```
def mqtt_initialisation():
    mod = '(messaging.initialisation) '
    ## establish callback routines - actions to take when events occur
    G_mqtt_client.on_connect = on_mqtt_connect
    G_mqtt_client.on_disconnect = on_mqtt_disconnect
    G_mqtt_client.on_message = message_received
    G_mqtt_client.on_log = on_mqtt_log
    G_mqtt_client.username_pw_set(params.G_broker_user, params.G_broker_pwd)
    G_mqtt_client.connect(params.G_broker_url, params.G_broker_port)
    G_mqtt_client.loop_start()
    main_log.debug(mod + "after Mqtt client loop start")

def on_mqtt_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    main_log.info("MQTT Connected With Result Code " + str(rc))  ## happens at start and if re-connected
    do_subscribe()

def on_mqtt_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    main_log.info("MQTT Client Got Disconnected")  ## this appears if, say, mosquitto goes offline

def on_mqtt_log(client, userdata, level, buff):
    main_log.info("MQTT Client error ...") 
    main_log.info(buff)
```

Comment: Give you are **try**ing to **catch** an error have you tried that?

Comment: Of course! - how could I forget the obvious easy solution; thank you. I will give it a go tomorrow

Comment: hardillb - it worked a treat thank you. :)

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it